# How do you retrieve only Total Unique Visitors from Google Analytics API with PHP

Tags: google-analytics-api

I've been looking at this tutorial http://www.codediesel.com/php/reading-google-analytics-data-from-php/ but am struggling as I only want to retrieve the total number of unique visitors which is a metric.

It appears that you have to use a 'dimension' to get the 'metric' when using their API.

Any ideas on how I can avoid using a dimension as all I want is the total.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Dimension is not mandatory.

Use:

**Metric**: ga:visitors and do mention the **start-date** and **end-date** to get the data in the desired range, which is required.
You will get the desired total.( **P.S.** The [calculation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/community/export_changelog.html) of ga:visitors has been changed to return the number of unique visitors across the date range )

Answer (score 2):

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$profileId = 'UA-00000000-1';

$yesterday=$startDate=$endDate=date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24 );

$metrics = 'sessions';

$results = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profileId, $startDate, $endDate, 'ga:'.$metrics);
```

Requires - https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client